# Text Base User Interface Library for (C or C++) Windows?

Tags: c++, c

is there any good TUI library (in C or C++) for Widndows?
I've found pdCurses which is more like the ncurses but it lacks a lot of nCurses libraries.

If you would ask on why am I finding a TUI library in 21th Century, It's because for a school project (Gosh those old programming teachers!)

Thanks! :)

Comment: If pdCurses doesn't contain what you need, you should probably be specific about what it doesn't do that you actually need.

Comment: @MichaelMadsen pdCurses lacks a lot of nCurses header files like the Menu.h library

Comment: Lacking a library is not necessarily a problem; it's only a problem if you *need* that library for something and cannot easily replicate similar functionality on your own. Without knowing *exactly* what you're missing, we can't know if any proposed alternative actually meets your requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cygwin has a fully functional ncurses, I think.

Of course, if you build with Cygwin, it needs Cygwin to run, but that's the deal.

Whenever I've dealt with TUI apps, pdCurses has always been enough, but we didn't need that much.

Comment: I just installed cygwin on my windows 7 pc and I'm using codeblocks as my IDE. I've set the compiler settings to Cygwin GCC.. Now, How do I use nCurses for my project? Thanks man

Comment: Ensure that you installed the Cygwin ncurses dev package. If you installed everything, then you have. If you're not sure, rerun setup and it acts as a package manager. From there on, it's just a case of including the right headers, and linking against the right libraries - they should all be installed in the "standard place", from Cygwin GCC's perspective.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Turbovision](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tvision/) port for Windows.
Turbovision was a TUI created by Borland back in the DOS days and also used in their products.

More info can also be [found here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_Vision/)

Comment: I think the Allegro game library can do similar kinds of menus.